# You are running Node 12.13.0. Create React App requires Node 14 or higher. Please update your version of Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

Im creating a new react project using create-react-app but it gives an error that says "You are running Node 12.13.0.
Create React App requires Node 14 or higher.
Please update your version of Node."

i have tried many things which i found in online articles but did not work.

Comment: did you tried to update your Node package? I suggest to use [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

Answer (score 1):

try using NVM (node version manager) is a portable solution for managing multiple versions of node.

```
nvm install node
nvm use node
nvm install --lts
nvm use --lts
```

`install and use` to install the latest version and use it.